# Should I build my form based on a query in order to see attributes of two related entities?

Tags: forms, ms-access, relationship

I am building a database in Microsoft Access 2016, and I have two relations (tables): a Personnel table and a Daily Activity table. The Daily Activity table is referencing the Personnel table through a 1 to many relationship (Employee Number is a foreign in the Daily Activity table).

I am building a form for users to enter their daily activity, and I would like the users to be able to pick their name or call sign and not just some randomly generated primary key established through autonumber ( I know, eventually, users will have their own individual profiles that automatically identifies them in the DBMS).

If I build a form based solely on the Daily Activity table, the lookup field for the Employee Number of Personnel table is some randomly generated number that may not be very useful for each employee to identify themselves. Therefore, should I build a query based on the two tables and use that query upon which to base the form, using ALL fields from the Daily Activity table and say, First Name, Last Name (I actually have a concatenation question for a name join, which I will probably use as well if possible), call sign, and of course the Employee Number field?

Comment: That's one way to display related info - don't allow edit of fields from Personnel. Another is form/subform arrangement - main form bound to Personnel and subform bound to DailyActivity. Another approach is for textboxes to reference columns of combobox. This is a design issue, not a programming question and not really suited to SO.

Comment: sorry for the delay, the website bugged and it took me 12 hours to have time to finish posting the answer.

Comment: @June7 Duly noted...somewhat new to this...I just read certain parts of the help section...now I get it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are finding out even the database designer doesn't want to deal with the primary keys directly.  The solution is to use a lookup.  A look up is when you show an understandable label instead of the underlying number.  While access allows you to use the table design mode to add a lookup to a column in a table,

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-or-delete-a-lookup-field-87e84cbd-d60c-4473-8a98-3e391c42f239

, experience has taught me to leave the tables alone.  The access friendly approach is to use combo boxes in your forms and reports.  When I Start with the form wizard, I usually delete the DailyActivityID textbox:

[image]

or don't even include it when using the form wizard:

[image]

Behind the scenes DailyID is still there linkiing your tables, the form user just doesn't see it.

Next we provide a lookup for employee number by replacing the bound textbox with a combobox.  Just right click the EmployeeNumber textbox to see the option to change to a combobox.  In this case once you have the combobox make sure the bound column is 1, Then set the column count to 2 and the column widths to 0 and 1 like here:
[image]

Then change the row source property so EmployeeNumber is the invisible 0 width column:

[image]

You could also use a calculated column to show the employees full name instead:

[image]

Now the form shows a more user friendly name.  To cycle through the records use the record selectors at the bottom of the form.

[image]

Next I usually remove the record selectors and replace them with another combobox in the header.

http://vbahowto.com/how-to-make-a-ms-access-filter-form-with-combobox-using-vba/